# Using private mibs with snmpv3

Tags: pysnmp

I am using below mentioned example to send v3 trap with custom notification mib

http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/agent/ntforg/trap-v3.html

But the sendNotification function is accepting only the dotted format as in the example ..

```
 What should I do to pass the symbols instead ?
```

E.g.(' MY-MIB:testTrap') instead of (1,3,2,0....)

Comment: Please put the code here in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are linking a historical pysnmp documentation. Please, refer to the [actual one](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/agent/ntforg/common-notifications.html#snmpv2c-trap-via-notification-type).

To pass MIB symbols you should use `ObjectIdentifier` class which turns MIB names into OIDs behind the scenes.

But SNMP notifications can be quite complicated because they may imply certain other MIB objects to be automatically included with the notification being sent.

But you can still add whatever MIB objects you want through [NotificationType.addVarBinds](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#mib-notification-types).

Here's a simple example:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    sendNotification(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData('public'),
        UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 162)),
        ContextData(),
        'trap',
        NotificationType(
            ObjectIdentity('MY-MIB', 'testTrap')
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Okay  Thanks .
But how do I use
 snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(snmpEngine) with the example

Comment: You should use ContextData() for that. Also, my example uses SNMP v2c. SNMP context only makes sense within SNMPv3.

Comment: Thanks Ilya that helped . I am getting one more error .pasted the code above .

Answer (score 0):

```
"Hi again below is a snippet of the way I am using the code .  "

from pysnmp.entity import engine, config

from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp

from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntforg, context

from pysnmp.proto.api import v2c

from pysnmp.proto import rfc1902

from pysnmp.smi import builder

file = open("."+"/file.txt","r")
line = file.read()
fields = line.split(",")
file.close()

file = open("."+"/credentials.txt","r")

cred = file.read()

fields = cred.split(",")

file.close()

snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine(snmpEngineID=v2c.OctetString(hexValue=cred[0]))

config.addV3User(snmpEngine, cred[1], config.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol, cred[2], config.usmAesCfb128Protocol, cred[3])

config.addTargetParams(snmpEngine, 'my-creds', 'traptest', 'authPriv')

config.addSocketTransport(snmpEngine,  udp.domainName, udp.UdpSocketTransport().openClientMode())

config.addTargetAddr(snmpEngine, 'my-nms', udp.domainName, ('127.0.0.1', 162), 'my-creds', tagList='all-my-managers')

config.addNotificationTarget(snmpEngine, 'my-notification', 'my-filter', 'all-my-managers', 'trap')

config.addContext(snmpEngine, '')

config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 3, 'traptest', 'authPriv', (), (), (1,3,6))

snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(snmpEngine)

ntfOrg = ntforg.NotificationOriginator()

ntfOrg.snmpContext = snmpContext

ntfOrg.sendNotification(

    snmpEngine,

    'my-notification',

    (1,3,6,1,4,1,46033,1,1,2,2),

    (((1,3,6,1,4,1,46033,1,1,1,1), v2c.OctetString(fields[0])),)

)

print('Notification is scheduled to be sent')
```